# Interpolation of a list defined on a region

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a three-dimensional table (each element has the form { x, y, f( x, y ) }), and the x, y coordinates spans a region of a parallelogram. If I do a list contour plot of the data, it gives the following figure (because the list is so big I cannot upload it here, sorry for that):
[image]
Now I want to use Interpolation to obtain an interpolated function, however, when I tried to do that, I got error messages like:

> Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1.
>
> The element mesh has insufficient quality of -2.80565*10^-13. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements.

Hope someone with experience can help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even though you cannot share the original data, perhaps you can create a small toy problem using generated data that can serve as an MWE.

Comment: I see. I have modified the table so that mma can interpolate it.